# How to stop insert data in second table if value is $open_bal = 0.00

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to stop insert data if my $open_bal is 0

My code:

```
public function createConsignor($MyData, $open_bal)
{
    $query_result = $this->db->insert('ts_users', $MyData);
    extract($MyData);
    $userInsertId   = $this->db->insert_id();
    $openingBalTrxn = [
        'voucher_amount'             => $open_bal,
        'voucher_person_account_id'  => $userInsertId,
        'voucher_creation_timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];
    if ($open_bal !== 0) {
        $this->db->insert('ts_voucher', $openingBalTrxn);
        if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        // do not enter data in ts_voucher table
    }
    return $query_result;
}
```

If `$open_bal` have some value then I want to insert data in `ts_voucher` table
I am trying `if($open_bal !==0){` like this but it insert data in `ts_voucher` table.

Comment: check that condition like `!empty($open_bal)`

Comment: After `print_r($open_bal);` it shows value is `0.00`

Comment: Change the test from `$open_bal !== 0` to `$open_bal != 0`

Comment: @farhantechno that 0.00 is data

Comment: check with floatval or intval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `empty()` function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

```
<?php
public function createConsignor($MyData, $open_bal)
{
    $query_result = $this->db->insert('ts_users', $MyData);
    extract($MyData);
    $userInsertId = $this->db->insert_id();


    if (empty($open_bal) || $open_bal == 0) {

        return; // don't insert
    } else {

        $openingBalTrxn = array(
            'voucher_amount' => $open_bal,
            'voucher_person_account_id' => $userInsertId,
            'voucher_creation_timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );

        $this->db->insert('ts_voucher', $openingBalTrxn);

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {

            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            return true;
        }


    }


    return $query_result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Its still insert data

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
public function createConsignor($MyData, $open_bal)
{
    $query_result = $this->db->insert('ts_users', $MyData);
    //extract($MyData);
    $userInsertId   = $this->db->insert_id();
    $openingBalTrxn = [ 'voucher_amount'             => $open_bal,
                        'voucher_person_account_id'  => $userInsertId,
                        'voucher_creation_timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')];
    if (!empty($open_bal) && $open_bal > 0) {
        $this->db->insert('ts_voucher', $openingBalTrxn);
        if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        // do not enter data in ts_voucher table
    }
    return $query_result;
}
```

Comment: Nicely explained